# Remove parenthesis (and add period) from gb4e examples

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I'm using the [gb4e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) package to number my linguistic examples, cf. the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \gll Dies ist ein Beispiel\\
    This is an example\\
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A style sheet I am following requires the numbers to appear as `1.` rather than `(1)`, but I'm not able to find anything the `gb4e` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/gb4e-doc.pdf) that helps me figuring out how to properly redefine this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no interface for changing it, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@exe
  {(\thexnumi)}
  {\thexnumi.}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \gll Dies ist ein Beispiel\\
    This is an example\\
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Note.*** `(\thexnumi)` is the only place in `gb4e.sty` that contains parentheses surrounding variable data.